# Mac excel opening files as read-only but has full access

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, read-only

I have a user who is trying to open an .xlsx file and modify its contents. However, the user is constantly faced with the message saying that someone else is in it. I have checked the Open Files on the server and no is in the file, also the person who is apparently locking it has left the company and the account has been deleted.

When looking at the permissions of the file the user has read-write access as well as the file not having a locked status on the Get Info window.

The version of Mac Excel that is being used is 12.3.6, and has not have any other issues opening other Excel sheets.